# Calculate X & Y of coordinate from byte array with known width & height

Tags: c#, arrays, math

My input is a single byte array. I know it's width and height and the length of the entire byte array. How do I iterate through each x & y coordinate? I can figure out the current x coordinate with the mod operation but I'm drawing a blank on logic for determining my y position.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= sender.Count(); i++)
{
    // figure out x & y
    int x = i % width;
    int y =
    Color c = pal[sender[i]];

    bmp.SetPixel(x, y, c);
}
```

Comment: `y = i / width;` (integer division).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to FBergo for the answer. I knew I was missing something very obvious!

```
for (int i = 0; i <= sender.Count(); i++)
{
    int x = i % width;
    int y = i / width; 
    Color c = pal[sender[i]];

    bmp.SetPixel(x, y, c);
}
```